# Product categories vs. business categories

Tags: e-commerce, categories

I'm developing an e-commerce site and I'm facing a problem. The requirement I need to fulfill is: given a certain string like "lock", "tennis", "cinema" or "scaffold" entered by an user, I should display both profiles and product postings matching that query.

That leads me to these conclusions:

a) I should classify **profiles (what they do):** maybe some sort of "business category". I face a problem here, it's almost impossible to create a list that covers all the business activities in the world, so I've been reading some good questions here and liked the strategy of creating a 1 or 2 level hierarchy and then capture the user feedback automatically through reusable tags.

The idea here is to keep the keywords that are more likely to be thought of and so with best odds of being searched for.

By the way, is there a really good business category list out there that I'm missing?

b) I should classify **products and services (what they offer)**: with a similar approach, I liked using some fixed categories and then let users use persistent tags. I ask you again if there is a category list out there that really rocks.

Questions:

1) Do you like what I've just described? Based on your experiences do you think it might work or will I drown in a tag sea?

2) Sometimes both product and business hierarchies are kind of redundant. There are some people that describe their businesses like "theater", "bank", "dentist" and that's not a product or service but rather what they actually are. But there are plenty of cases where people say "(sale/manufacturing) cars", "(manufacturing) pottery", and so on. Their business activity is chiefly determined by the product or service they're selling or producing. What's your take on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this is ror_ecommerce.  I used a tree for product_types.

So you could sell:

Furniture => Livingroom => Chairs

Filtering by Livingroom would also give items that have a product_type pointing to Chairs.

To make it more complex I would first fight the business person.
Second I would create a model where product has many product_types.  Thus you need a join table between product_type and product.

**Answer to your question:**

1) You will probably drown because categories are infinite.  Limit the number of tags or make an admin interface that your business people can populate.  If not your business folks will request you to do this work over and over again.

2) It sounds like Your tree would look like this:

- sale/manufacturing => cars
- sale/manufacturing  => pottery
- bank => personal
- bank => business

thus if someone just wants a bank they get results for personal and business.  but they can further refine the search to just personal banking.

It also sounds like the business and product hierarchies are completely redundant.  I would really fight a business guy saying anything else because a future requirement will be to relate business and personal hierarchies.  If they are the same it will be easy.  You might want a type flag on the list for personal / business / both.  it will be a lot easier to remove the flag if it's not needed.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks for your time, man. Your description of the product_type fits what we have today. As for the redundancy, I agree with you and definitely convinced myself that both "tags soups", business and product (in case we use tags - or hierachies) should be part of the same set. I forgot to mention that we don't control the content published but rather, it's user-generated so we've had a hard time with users saying they couldn't find some specific category.

Comment: ebay does something like this when you sell something.  you should go through their auction creation process.  They do limit the number of categories a user can choose.